# I used hsearch, can I add hsearch_r later? - mix hsearch and hsearch_r

Tags: c

all,
I used hcreate, hsearch in my program and it works fine. Later I find I need another hash table. Can I just start to use hcreate_r, hsearch_r to create and use this second hash table? I don't want to go back and change the existing code that uses hcreate, hsearch.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can. The _r versions will not interfere with the hashtable that the non _r functions use.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. The `_r` suffix in many POSIX/C functions denotes that a function is [reentrant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrant_%28subroutine%29). This means that more than one call can be in executing the function at the same time. The non `_r` forms of these functions reuse global memory (or [TLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage)), while the reentrant forms require that you pass the context into each call.